# Read label values and store into a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read data from a website and have that data stored into a variable.
Example:

http://www.example.com/example-info.php ->

Name: Bob

Address: 1234 Street

Telephone: 000-000-0000

Email: Bobs-email@nothing.com

What I would like to do is get the value from the label "Name" which is Bob and store it into a variable such as "Username". or "Telephone" and store the value into a variable named "Phone". Can someone point me in the right direction. Perhaps I need to use Mechanize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to [screen scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) the website?  If so, using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) are good things to look at.

```
import requests
x = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
if x.status_code == 200:
    print x.content
```

`x.content` in the above scenario will hold the data/html from the page you send the request to.  Then, you could use BeautifulSoup or regex to extract out the particular information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `dict` to store your keys and values, and a mapping dict of the translations

```
mapping = {"Telephone": "Phone", "Name": "Username"}
details = {}

details[mapping.get(web_key, web_key)] = web_value
```

So for example

```
>>> web_dict = {"Name": "Bob", "Address": "1234 Street", "Telephone": "000-000-0000", "Email": "Bobs-email@nothing.com"}
>>>    
>>> for web_key, web_value in web_dict.iteritems():
...     details[mapping.get(web_key, web_key)] = web_value
...
>>> print details
{'Username': 'Bob', 'Phone': '000-000-0000', 'Email': 'Bobs-email@nothing.com', 'Address': '1234 Street'}
```

Of course this is only half an answer, you'll need something to parse the html into a dictionary to begin with.